# 2300 Vac 200 Hz electric shock dangerous?

Tags: ac, safety, induction

I was working on a induction furnace and received a 2300Vac/200Hz shock.

I suffer from headaches, constant fatigue, and sore arms and legs 2 months later.

Should I be worried that I might have internal damage?

Work has only just told me this after initially saying it was a 30-40Vdc shock through earth leak system.

Comment: Yes, its a really good idea to ask random dudes on the interwebs about this instead of a real doctor...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with electronic design.

Comment: Though I also think that it would be better to ask a doctor first, I don't think asking for medical background on electrical accidents is offtopic since electrical engineers should know what systems and parameters cause damage.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has to do with medical effects of something. **OP SHOULD IMMEDIATELY SEE A MEDICAL EXPERT**.

Comment: Although asking for medical advice on the internet is not wise, in itself the question is NOT off-topic, **on the contrary**, it's all about electrical risk in a working environment. Where else on SE such a question could be on-topic, otherwise?

Comment: is it 200Hz or 200 kHz?

Comment: Thanks for responses,I have seen doctor re this already and been having blood tests for ckp levels,was more just wondering what differences are between the 2 different shocks I was told I suffered,thought someone on here might be able to say.investigation report said 2300 vac,200hz.

Comment: muscle tension increases with pulse rate and amplitude so I would expect more strain from 200Hz than 60Hz more muscle strain..

Answer (score 4):

Please, **go and see a doctor AS SOON AS POSSIBLE, because you could have some neural damage!** See for example [this article from CETRI (Chicago Electrical Trauma Rehabilitation Institute)](https://cetri.org/electrical_injury.html). Some excerpts:

> Even without visible burns, electric shock survivors may be faced with long-term muscular pain and discomfort, fatigue, headache, problems with peripheral nerve conduction and sensation, inadequate balance and coordination, and other additional symptoms. Electrical injury, also, often leads to problems with neurocognitive function, affecting speed of mental processing, attention, concentration, and memory.

You should have done it immediately after the accident. From what you say it seems that you employer lied to you or misled you. IANAL, but in some countries this is a violation (by your employer) of safety regulations which, if deliberate, could also be prosecuted.

If possible, seek also legal advice. You may be in the position of suing your employer.